# Make Flex Plot Chart items toggled to show/hide item's label

Tags: apache-flex, charts, toggle, label

I made an application for generating a plot chart based on previously calculated data (X,Y). After plotting the data on the chart, I tried to make the items (dots) to show a label (through addChild an external custom label component) when a user click on the dots (for example: if a user click on a chart item, the corresponding ID number will show beside the dot).

Although everything works fine, I can't make the items toggled (for example: if a dot is already clicked and label ID is visible, on next click on the same dot I want to hide (removeChild) the label component which corresponds to that item)... A simple example code of what I did so far is attached:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="417" height="468" backgroundGradientAlphas="[1.0, 1.0]" backgroundGradientColors="[#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF]">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.charts.events.ChartItemEvent;
    import mx.charts.HitData;
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

     [Bindable]
     public var ARR:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {ID:1, Y:2000, X:1500},
        {ID:2, Y:1000, X:200},
        {ID:3, Y:1500, X:500},
        {ID:4, Y:500, X:300},
        {ID:5, Y:1000, X:450},
        {ID:6, Y:2000, X:500}
     ]);

     private function labels_plot1(plot:String, dotIndex:int, labelID:String):void {
            var ID_lab:ID_label = new ID_label();
            if(this[plot].series[0] == ID_lab.parent){
                this[plot].series[0].removeChild(ID_lab);
            }else{
                this[plot].series[0].addChild(ID_lab);
                ID_lab.x = this[plot].series[0].getChildAt(dotIndex).x + 8;
                ID_lab.y = this[plot].series[0].getChildAt(dotIndex).y + 1.2;
                ID_lab.ID_txt.htmlText = "<B>" + labelID  + "</B>";
            }
     }

     private function dotClickEvent(event:ChartItemEvent):void{
        labels_plot1(event.currentTarget.id, event.hitData.chartItem.index, event.hitData.item.ID);
     }

  ]]></mx:Script>
     <mx:PlotChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{ARR}" itemClick="dotClickEvent(event)">
        <mx:series>
           <mx:PlotSeries id="pl"
                xField="X"
                yField="Y"
                displayName="Plot 1"
            />
        </mx:series>
        <mx:annotationElements>
            <mx:CartesianDataCanvas id="canvas" includeInRanges="true"/>
        </mx:annotationElements>
     </mx:PlotChart>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

I tried almost everything, but with no success... How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first check in your function could not be true, that is why the children are not removed. First of all you should not create a new label before you have got to know either or not you need a new one.

In your case I would use the property name of a component to save the dotIndex there. The dotIndex is uniq, so you can check anytime if the label exists by using the function getChildByName(dotIndex.toString()).

I also prefer to add new Labels direct into a separate container or in our case into the application itself. Here is something you can try to do:

```
        private function labels_plot1(plot:String, dotIndex:int, labelID:String):void {

            var dispObj:DisplayObject = this.getChildByName(dotIndex.toString());

            if (dispObj != null)
            {
                this.removeChild(dispObj);
            }
            else
            {
                var ID_lab:Label = new Label();

                ID_lab.x = this[plot].series[0].getChildAt(dotIndex).x + 8 + 60;
                ID_lab.y = this[plot].series[0].getChildAt(dotIndex).y + 1.2 + 4;

                ID_lab.text = labelID;
                ID_lab.name = dotIndex.toString();
                this.addChild(ID_lab);
            }
        }
```

I don't have your component ID_Label, so I have used a normal Label here.

Comment: Thanks Anton... This is exactly what I wanted... Regards, Nikola

Comment: Hi Nikola, there is one thing you should take into account. The Labels can prevent you from clicking on the points if they lie close to them, because they are targets as well. It is not a big problem to let them go through and achive the points.